# Forming words from letters

Tags: combinatorics

If we have five letters e.g. a,b,c,d,e

a. How many four-letter words can we make that have exactly two vowels and two consonants?

b. from (a), how many of those words have distinct vowels?

Comment: Hint: Look at permutations, and assume some of the things you want are already picked.

Comment: *edited to make it simpler*

Comment: (Part (a) for now) For now I can think about the vowel part. I can have ae, aa and ee, but so the 4-letter word can be aexx, aaxx and eexx. But that means I need to add more cases for the xx part (consonants), and with each case is a different way to permute it (since there are repetitions). This is where I'm stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) 
$2^2=4$ possibilities when it comes to vowels. $3^2=9$ possibilities when it comes to consonants (**assuming that consonants can also be repeated**, you did not say that they cannot). Then $\binom{4}{2}=6$ possibilities to place e.g. the vowels. That gives $4\times 9\times 6=216$ possibilities.

b) 
Among the possibilities for vowels there are $2$ with distinct vowels leading to $2\times 9\times 6=108$ possibilities.

**If consonants are not allowed to be repeated** then $9=3^2$ above must be replaced by $6=3\times2$ in both cases.

This gives $4\times 6\times 6=144$ as answer on a) and $2\times 6\times 6=72$ as answer on b).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I removed the part where I said "vowels can be repeated", because all letters can be repeated in fact. And this helped solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. First we will **choose** two consonants from the three we have.
   So $${3\choose2} = 3$$
   For the vowels, we have three choices:**(a,e),(a,a) and (e,e)**.
   So the total number of words we can make is
   $$3*(2*(\frac{P^4_3}{2!})+1*(P^4_3))$$
   $$=\boxed{144}$$ 
   We multiply here by $2$ for the case of **(a,a)** and **(e,e)** and divide it by $2!$ for the repition, since there are $2!$ ways to arrange $2$ things. We multiply by $1 for the **(a,e)** case.
2. For the second part we have
   $$3*(P^4_3) = 72$$

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 consonants among which we can choose 2. This can be done in $3 \choose 2$ ways. Now, choosing the vowels can be done as, $2 \choose 2$ ways of choosing 2 different vowels and $2 \choose 1$ way of choosing same vowels. So, vowels can be chosen in 3 ways and consonants can be chosen in 3 ways.

When vowels are identical, the number of permutations are $\dfrac{3\times 2\times 4!}{2!}=72$ ways.

When the vowels are distinct, the number of permutations are $3\times 1\times 4!=72$ ways.

Answer to part (a): $144$

Answer to part (b): $72$